# Encoding issue with org.json.simple.JSONObject - turning ★ to â˜…

Tags: java, json, character-encoding, gson

I have the following JSON file:

```
[
    { "meeting_place": "★ Cafe Roma ★" },
     ...
]
```

I'm using `JsonReader` & `Gson` to read the file:

```
JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(currentFile)));
jsonReader.beginArray();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
    JSONObject currentJsonObject = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, JSONObject.class);
    // work on the currentJsonObject
}
```

All worked great until today and the file was read correctly by the JsonReader with all the special signs in it.

Today, all of a sudden, when reading the value from the JSON object, the value of the `★` is read as `â˜…`

In the *pom* file, I declare the following depedencies:

- json-simple version 1.1
- gson version 2.8.2

I don't think it is encoding issue, as the file was read ok till today with the above code that has no encoding specification in it.

Comment: Use UTF-8 to preserve ★

Comment: ex. new String(jo.getString("name").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");

Comment: You now don't think it's an encoding issue (although you added the character-encoding tag to your question) ? Have you tried what I described in my answer? Reading 3 accented/special characters instead of 1 expected special character is a typical symptom of trying to read a stream in a single-byte character encoding like ISo--8859-1 or some Windows codepage, which was encoded while writing in UTF-8 (UTF-8 uses multiple bytes to encode a single character if it's codepoint 
 value is over 127)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the character encoding in the constructor of `InputStreamReader`. Assuming it's the usual UTF-8 encoding, you should use:

```
JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(
        new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(currentFile), 
                              StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```